# hbase export snapshot - CorruptedSnapshotException

Tags: hadoop, hbase, snapshot

I am working on a project which has 1TB data in Hbase. For backup purpose I read about snapshot.

hbase snapshot is on a cluster and I want to export to different cluster and I am getting

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.CorruptedSnapshotException):
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.CorruptedSnapshotException:

So what other files do I need to include in my export?

and is it possible to restore the snapshot in another cluster like moving the snapshot directory from one cluster to another via winscp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting CorruptedSnapshotException is due to this reason *the snapshot info from the filesystem is not [valid](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/snapshot/CorruptedSnapshotException.html)*. So, please check whether your
export command was right.

**example:**

```
hbase class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot snapshot30072017 -copy-to hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase -mappers 8 -bandwidth 100
```

Please read this [Issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11618).

The above command has eight map jobs which will run to export all snapshots to another cluster with a limiting bandwidth of 100 MB/s.

**Note :**

The **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot** tool **copies** all the data related to a snapshot (*HFiles, logs, and snapshot metadata*) to **another cluster**.

snapshot details can be found under **this hdfs location**

**/apps/hbase/data/.hbase-snapshot/** (cloudera vm path), please copy those files to another cluster
and restore using `'restore_snapshot 'snapshot_name''`

Please read this [HBase snapshot documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops.snapshots.html).